# Textarea having white space before content in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, .net

[image]

In IE10, textarea showing white space before content after saving in asp.net,then how to remove that white space using jquery or javascript or css it is working fine in IE9 and IE8 but not in IE10 and text should be display in place of white space like second image:

[image]

Comment: post your code or fiddle link.

Comment: share your code what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trim()` function

```
var str = "       Hello World!        ";
alert(str.trim());
```

The trim() method removes whitespace from both sides of a string.
Note: The trim() method does not change the original string.

For browsers that do not support the trim() method, you can remove whitespaces from both sides of a string with a regular expression:

```
function myTrim(x) {
    return x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');
}

function myFunction() {
    var str = myTrim("        Hello World!        ");
    alert(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve with using below approaches:

**using jQuery :**

```
$('#textareId').html(vdt_demo_table_string.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;'));
```

**Using CSS:**

```
textarea{
white-space:pre;
}
```

OR

```
textarea{
white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```

Hope it will helps you.

Thanks